# commas in arrays, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to make is a system that if you check a checkbox, some text appears in a text-area. When you uncheck it, the text disappears.
Now I got most of the code working, if you check a checkbox some text will appear, and if you uncheck it the text will disappear.

However, the commas stay, so I am left with a text-area with loads of commas.

code :

```js
let text = [];
let counter = 0;

function boxChecker(a, b) {

  let checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck" + a);

  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

  for (var i = 0; i < counter + 1; i++) {
    text[counter] = b;
  }

  counter++;

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    textarea.value = text;
  } else {
    text.pop();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (text[i] === b) {
        text.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  textarea.value = text;
}
```

Here's what I get right now:

[image]

Comment: Can you please supply the HTML as well?

Comment: do you want to keep the order of the checkboxes? what is `a` and what is `b`?

Comment: There's no point in assigning `textarea.value` in the `if`, since you assign it again at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give all the checkboxes a common class. Get the values of all the checked ones and display that, rather than using function parameters to pass the checkbox number and value to display.

```
function boxChecker() {
    let allValues = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".myCheck:checked")).map(el => el.value);
    document.getElementById("textarea").value = allValues.join(",");
}
```

Comment: in all honesty this is prob the best answer

Comment: Thank you for this, however I dont understand every code you use in there. Ill do some research!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you assign array element to an index, it keeps other empty elements before it in the array causing the commas.

`text[counter] = b;`

Instead you could just push the element in the back of the array.

```js
let text = [];
let counter = 0;

function boxChecker(a, b) {

  let checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck" + a);

  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

  text.push(b);

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    textarea.value = text;
  } else {
    text.pop();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (text[i] === b) {
        text.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  textarea.value = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to add the checked checkboxes to an array and then use join with a comma delimiter to separate them as a string, then put that value in the textarea.

```js
function addCheckedToTextarea(checkbox, textarea, results) {
  checkbox.checked
    ? results.push(checkbox.value) 
    : results.pop(checkbox.value);
  textarea.innerHTML = results.join(", ");
}

let checked = [];
document
  .querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")
  .forEach(cb => {
    cb.addEventListener('change', () => 
      addCheckedToTextarea(cb, document.getElementById("textarea"), checked));
  });
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="One">
  One
</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Two">
  Two
</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Three">
  Three
</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Four">
  Four
</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Five">
  Five
</label>
<br />
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain the array by adding and filtering the boxes.

```js
function box({ value, checked }) {
    if (checked) text.push(value);
    else text = text.filter(v => v !== value);
    document.getElementById("textarea").value = text;
}

let text = [];
```

```html
blabla2 <input type="checkbox" value="blabla2" onchange="box(this)"><br>
blabla3 <input type="checkbox" value="blabla3" onchange="box(this)"><br>
blabla4 <input type="checkbox" value="blabla4" onchange="box(this)"><br>
blabla5 <input type="checkbox" value="blabla5" onchange="box(this)"><br>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```